# $(\mathfrak{g},K)$-Module where $K$ is a field?

Tags: modules, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am reading through *Finite groups of Lie type_ conjugacy classes and complex characters* by Roger Carter, and came across this passage where Carter is setting up a special class of module to give a representation $\rho$ of a lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$:

> Let $\frak{g}$ be a finite dimensional Lie algebra over an arbitrary field $k$, and let $M$ be a finite dimensional $k\frak{g}$-module.

Im assuming by this he means a $(\mathfrak{g},k)$-module because we are building the machinery to prove the Jacobson-Morozov theorem. For a $(\mathfrak{g},k)$-module though, $k$ has to be a maximal compact subgroup of the Lie group corresponding to $\frak{g}$ -- but arbitrary fields are not compact?

Was I wrong to assume that a $k\mathfrak{g}$-module was a $(\mathfrak{g},k)$-module by some different notation? Unfortunately, Carter doesn't elaborate much more on what he means by this. Any suggested readings would be appreciated, I am quite new to the study of lie algebras and don't really know what I am doing yet!

Comment: [$(\mathfrak{g},K)$-module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(g,K)-module) is meant for a maximal compact subgroup $K$ of $G$ with $Lie(G)=\mathfrak{g}$. So $K$ is not a field there.

Comment: @DietrichBurde That's what I figured, but I couldn't find anything on a "$k\mathfrak{g}$-module" so I thought maybe I was missing something. Is there another class of modules that make sense in this context?

Comment: It could be just a $\mathfrak{g}$-module, over a $k$-vector space. For a group, we have a $kG$-module, where $kG=k[G]$ is the group algebra.